# Splitting a String with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to create my own pattern to split a String with a regex expression.

Actually i want to split a String into sentences so i need a pattern like ". \p{Upper}"
I've tried to code it, but java doesn't accept it:

```
String[] phrase = txtbrut.split(". \p{Upper}");
```

Basically i need to split the text String with a pattern like : dot-space-CapitalLetter

If someone know how to create his own pattern.

Comment: Please elaborate what your problem is and what you have tried already to solve it. As a side remark, if you really plan to split a text into sentences will bring you only so far (consider e.g. abbreviations or ellipsis). There are a few toolkits which try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the string into sentences, you could do

```
String[] sentences = txtbrut.split("\\. (?=\\p{Upper})");
```

Note as per [Stephan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961935/splitting-a-string-with-regex-in-java/23961967#comment36916159_23961935), this will not handle cases where abbreviations and ellipsis occur